# Sql Query Sorting Issues

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, where-clause

I have got 2 fields in my db(sql server 2008) namely updateDate[Datetime] & calldate[datetime]. The sql query I am running to get the data from th db is :

```
Select * from [Clients] where [Timestamp] < GetDate() ORDER BY calldate, updateDate
```

Now the issue is the callbackdate has default value of minimum date , so if no date is passed , it adds the minimumdate, I want to add a check on the above query so it doesnt sort the records with calldate value is set to minimum date value. For instance if the calldate is minimumdate then that record should be sorted by renewal date.Is it possible to acheive something like this.

Any suggestions or advice will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: you can do this with a CASE statement in the order by clause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @minimumdate DATETIME

SELECT @minimumdate = MIN(calldate) FROM [Clients]

Select * 
from [Clients] 
where [Timestamp] < GetDate() 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN calldate = @minimumdate THEN updateDate ELSE calldate END
```

Comment: well there is no column as minimumdate , the minimum date is set by default

Answer (score 1):

```
Select YourColumns
from [Clients] 
where [Timestamp] < GetDate() 
order by 
    case when callDate = minimumDate then updateDate else callDate end, 
    updateDate
```

Comment: well there is no column as minimumdate , the minimum date is set by default

Answer (score 1):

try this (if minimunm date is 2009-01-01)

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN CallDate=DATE('2009-01-01') THEN RenewDate else CallDate END)
```